# Rails: How to make controller actions only available to associated users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, associations

I have a `Users` model and an associated `Company` model with correponding controllers that I built using scaffolding.

Each `company` action `[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` should only be accessible the associated `user`.

Rails scaffolding has generated the following code:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController 
    before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

<actions>

  private
    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end
```

This however allows any user to access any company, which is a security issue. I therefore changed the `set_company` method as follows:

```
def set_company
  if current_user.companies.find_by_id(params[:id]).present?
    @company = current_user.companies.find(params[:id])
  else
    redirect_to companies_url
  end
end
```

This seems to work correctly. Can anyone tell me if this is the correct way of dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that adding in the validation for the `set_company` method is confusing. It's generally a better idea to have methods do one thing. Perhaps you can create another before_action called `correct_user`

```
def correct_user
  @company = current_user.companies.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to companies_url if @company.nil?
end
```

Then you can simply add in another before_action

```
before_action :correct_user, [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

This keeps everything cleaner and makes your code easier to maintain so that other programmers (or your future self) will know exactly what each method does.

Hope that helps.